# Dojo Gantt Chart Example does not render

Tags: dojo

I simply took [dojo gantt chart example](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gantt/tests/test_Gantt.html) and put it in my code, and now **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2YjK/)**, and theres nothing rendered, without any errors. Did I miss something out? It appears onLoad does not run, in my Chrome Console network tab, theres no 404's tho, and it looks like every thing downloaded fine?

**UPDATE**

I think the problem here is with the require `GanttChart`. If I **[comment that out](http://jsfiddle.net/a2YjK/1/)**, at least I get into the `onLoad`

Comment: have you tried running it locally? (i.e. not against the CDN)  I wonder if something is wrong with the AMD conversion that prevents it from running cross-domain

Comment: I tried locally too, it appears the callback is not run. I think `GanttChart` does not load properly somehow

Comment: well, here's another data point: [it fails](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.2/dojo-release-1.7.2/dojox/gantt/tests/test_Gantt.html) on dojo 1.7.2.  You're running the nightly.  It could have been a bug in the loader that has since been fixed, or perhaps something like a circular reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the Gantt in Dojo 1.7.2 . When I switch to v 1.7.1 it works fine (for my implementation, and on your fiddle too).